# How to conditionally transpose in pandas (similar to SQL case when withn group by)

Tags: python, sql, pandas, transpose

I have a data frame like below

```
ID name       Value
1  Brand       B1
1  Color       C1 
1  Dimension   D1
2  Brand       B2
2  Color       C2 
2  Dimension   D2
```

I want to transpose it so that the result data frame is (Note I don't want to create a column for every name)

```
ID Brand Color
1  B1    C1
2  B2    C2
```

Explored "Unstack" in pandas but that will transpose all values of name . Is there a way to transpose only for selected values of name instead . What will be the pandas equivalent of  the below

```
Select Id , 
(case when name = "Brand" then value else end ) as brand ,
(case when name = "COlor" then value else end) as color
from table 
group by ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fabio's solution is good, but you don't have to copy the DataFrame:

```
name_filter = ['Brand','Color']

print(df[df.name.isin(name_filter)].pivot(index='ID', columns='name', values='Value'))
```

UPDATE:

```
df2 = df[df.name.isin(name_filter)].pivot(index='ID', columns='name', values='Value').reset_index()
print(df2.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
 ID Brand Color
  1    B1    C1
  2    B2    C2
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thanks Max and Fabio. Why do I get a separate column called name which has the 1st row as ID ? Is there a work around? Basically I just need column `names ID , brand and color `. Instead the column names are  `name , brand and color`

Comment: Yes but the Df should look like that . looks like you are converting the df to a string and printing the string.

Answer (score 3):

I would use [pivot](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as:

```
a = df.pivot(index='ID', columns='name', values='Value')
```

this returns:

```
name Brand Color Dimension
ID                        
1       B1   C1         D1
2       B2   C2         D2
```

then you can subselect only the columns you need:

```
a[['Brand','Color']]
```

that returns:

```
name Brand Color
ID              
1       B1   C1 
2       B2   C2
```

EDIT: IIUC, you can firstly mask your dataframe keeping only the values in the `name` columns you are interested in with:

```
df = df[df['name'].isin(['Brand','Color'])]
```

and then pivot as above.

Comment: Thanks Fabio . But I have around 100 +  distinct names and I want to create columns for 4,5 of them . If I use pivot, it will create a lot of columns unnecessarily before subsetting. Is there a more optimized solution